# TypeError: POST data should be bytes

Tags: python, api, typeerror

**This the background code for the below input code and when I try running it returns this error, can somebody help. I'm using Python 3.7.**

File "C:\Users\Sai\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1250, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)

TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

```
if request.data is not None:  # POST
        data = request.data
        if isinstance(data, str):
            msg = "POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, " \
                  "or a file object. It cannot be of type str."
            raise TypeError(msg)
        if not request.has_header('Content-type'):
            request.add_unredirected_header(
                'Content-type',
                'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        if (not request.has_header('Content-length')
                and not request.has_header('Transfer-encoding')):
            content_length = self._get_content_length(request)
            if content_length is not None:
                request.add_unredirected_header(
                        'Content-length', str(content_length))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain what you are trying to do including enough code that we can reproduce it. What code are you actually running? You seem to have posted the error handling code that actually produces the error (I'm guessing from inside a module you've imported, perhaps requests or urllib), not your own code that defines what is in request.data.

Comment: Seems like other people also had that problem before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError+POST+data+should+be+bytes

Comment: This is the input codeimport urllib.request, json
req = urllib.request.Request('https://api.fullcontact.com/v3/person.enrich')
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {Your API Key}')
data = json.dumps({
  "emails": [
    "email Id"
  ]
})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req,data)